# Generalised arcsine law of brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion

It is well known that for a standard brownian motion, the time spent above $0$ follows an arcsine distribution (whose density function is U-shaped). Can anyone tell me how to generalise this result to 'time spent above $x$'?

I imagine it is some beta distribution (given that the arcsine distribution is a special case), but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Eq. (15) in https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoap/1034968240 might be relevant

Comment: Ah, nice. That looks like the answer to me. Does that distribution have a name?

Comment: Not that I know...